# Is there a common term for types such as size_t, ptrdiff_t and uintmax_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, terminology

I need a widely accepted term that would describe *size_t*, *ptrdiff_t*, *intptr_t*, *uintptr_t*, *uintmax_t*, etc (so platform-dependent types which are mentioned in the Standard and having width varying depending on pointer size or widest integer width size) **together** as a set of types.

Obviously "memsize types" or "pointer size types" won't work because *intmax_t* is not tied to pointer size or memory block size.

Is there a widely accepted name for such set of types?

Comment: Integral types? I don't see how [tag:language-lawyer] fits here. Whatever a language lawyer says will by not be widely accepted. Unless you mean that whatever the standard says is widely accepted by definition.

Comment: I think I do the opposite and talk about specifically sized types as *fixed width types* (`like uint32_t`). Everything else I assume is platform dependent.

Comment: There is no name for that in the standard, and I also don't see how [language-lawyer] applies.

Comment: Anyways, I suppose if you absolutely need to come up with a single term, "the standard integer typedefs" might be fairly understandable and not factually wrong at least.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably call them "architecture defined types."